# Disable interruptions when displaying a 7-segment counter

Tags: c++, esp32

I have made a counter from 0 to 99 with 2 buttons. One button will be used to increase the counter and another to decrease it. Now, these actions with the buttons will be carried out through interruptions, which I already have implemented. My question is: Can you momentarily disable the interrupts when the counter value is displayed in the 7 segments? It is worth mentioning that I am using multiplexing to print the value of the counters in the 7 segments. I have already tried to interrupt the interruptions in the subroutine where the printing program is located, but the result is that it no longer allows me to increment the counter.

Here's the code:

```
int outArray[]={D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7};
int count=0, unidades=0, decenas=0, unidades1=0, decenas1=0;
const int pulsadora=D0;
const int pulsadord=D1;
const int timeThreshold = 150;
long startTime_pm = 0; 
long startTime_ph = 0; 


void IRAM_ATTR handleInterrupta() {
 if (millis() - startTime_ph > timeThreshold) {
   unidades++;
 if(unidades>9)
 {
   unidades=0;
   decenas++;
 }
 if(decenas>9)
 {
   decenas=0;
 }

   startTime_ph = millis();
 }
}


void IRAM_ATTR handleInterruptd() {
 if (millis() - startTime_pm > timeThreshold) {
   unidades--;
 if(unidades<0)
 {
   unidades=9;
   decenas--;
 }
 if(decenas<0)
 {
   decenas=9;
 }

   startTime_ph = millis();
 }
}

void vizualiza()
{

unidades1= unidades +16;

for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{

digitalWrite(outArray[i], bitRead(unidades1, i));

}
delay(10);
decenas1=decenas+32;
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
digitalWrite(outArray[i], bitRead(decenas1, i));
}
delay(10);

}

void setup() {

pinMode(pulsadora, INPUT);
pinMode(pulsadord, INPUT);
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
 pinMode(outArray[i], OUTPUT);
}
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pulsadora),handleInterrupta,FALLING);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pulsadord),handleInterruptd,FALLING);

}

void loop() {

 vizualiza();
 
}
```

Comment: Critical sections in an interrupt are to be avoided.  In many processor, when an interrupt occurs, all other interrupts are blocked.  You'll need to read the programmer's guide for your processor of System On a Chip (SOC).  You'll want to prioritize your interrupts, do slower stuff in lower priority interrupts.

Comment: One issue is that interrupts can get *stacked*.  In other words, consider a pipeline of interrupts.  If an ISR takes too long, the ISR may get invoked again after it exits.